# Can't get function to find multiple indexes of identical string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found this indexOf-Tryit on W3schools and decided to try modifying it into a function that finds index values for each instance of "Apple" and outputs them to a paragraph. I cannot get it to work and it's driving me mad.

I've tried using for and while-loops with many different variations.

```
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple", "Apple", "Tahiti", "Mango", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];

for (i=0; i < fruits.length; i++) {

    if (fruits[i] = fruits.indexOf("Apple")) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += fruits[i];
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "x"} 
}
}
```

I want the paragraph to display "0x2x45xx8x10" or "0245810" without the else-operation. What I get instead is "x224458881010".

Comment: Sounds like you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wL8un027/ (main issue: `=` is for assignment; for comparisons you need `==` or `===`. And please don't use w3schools)

Comment: Why should I not use W3schools? Please elaborate.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was `if (fruits[i] = fruits.indexOf("Apple"))` you're changing value of fruits[i]. Moreover you can directly compare the value and use the index as you're already looping through array.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple", "Apple", "Tahiti", "Mango", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];

for (i=0; i < fruits.length; i++) {

    if (fruits[i] === "Apple") {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "x"} 
}
}

myFunction()
```

```html
<div id='demo'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to `map` the string values to the index value if they match. If they don't match set a falsy value. Then use `filter` to remove all non matching values.

Passing in the array to be searched and the value you're looking for makes the function more reusable. And not returning a string allows the function to more flexible still. It's easy enough to join an array with `.join(',')`

```js
function findIndexesOf(arr, value) {
  return arr.map((e, i) => e == value ? i : null).filter( e => e != null)
}

let fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple", "Apple", "Tahiti", "Mango", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];


let appleIndexs = findIndexesOf(fruits, "Apple")
console.log("Apples:", appleIndexs.join(','))
console.log(appleIndexs)


let mangoIndexs = findIndexesOf(fruits, "Mango")
console.log(mangoIndexs)
```